# how to concatenate Sql query result With some strings?

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

Have to concatenate sql query result With some strings.
I am getting sql query result like this

```
+--------------------+
|    Some Value      |
+--------------------+
|abc,xyz,amar,akbar  |
+--------------------+
|   hjk,fed,fas      |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

I want to concatenate ' with each row result like this and I am using Sql server 2012.

```
+--------------------------+
|    Some Value            |
+--------------------------+
|'abc','xyz','amar','akbar'|
+--------------------------+
|   'hjk','fed','fas'      |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
```

Please help me..

Comment: PLEASE LOOK HERE http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `'` on the start and end of your string. Then `REPLACE` `,` with `','`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1580/0)

```
SELECT '''' + REPLACE(some_value, ',', ''',''') + '''' FROM tbl
```

Comment: thanks ...[Felix Pamittan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2203084/felix-pamittan)